# Display all listview items in messagebox c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a listview with subitems. The first 5 sub items are the name, items, total price, address and telephone.

The rest of the subitems contain the past list that I displayed for my order.

It is a pizzeria program and I want it to be able to get the customers info and order.

I can get the info but can't get the rest of the order.

I'm wondering how I can display the rest of my order if that makes sense.

Example Order:

```
Name: Claud
Items: 3
Total: 10.99
Address: (Blank)
Telephone: (Blank)
Order: Small Pizza
       -Bacon
       BreadSticks
```

Right now my messagebox looks like this:

```
Name: Claud
Items: 3
Total: 10.99
Address: (Blank)
Telephone: (Blank)
Order: Small Pizza
```

So I just want it to display the -Bacon and BreadSticks.

Source Code:

```
  private void CustomerInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem customers = new ListViewItem(fullName.Text);
        customers.SubItems.Add(totalcount.ToString());
        customers.SubItems.Add(total.ToString());
        customers.SubItems.Add(Address.Text);
        customers.SubItems.Add(telephone.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i < OrderlistBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            customers.SubItems.Add(OrderlistBox.Items[i].ToString());
        }
        Customers.Items.Add(customers);

        MessageBox.Show("Sent order for " + fullName.Text.ToString() + " to screen.");
        //CLEAR ALL FIELDS
        OrderlistBox.Items.Clear();
        fullName.Text = "";
        Address.Text = "";
        telephone.Text = "";
        totalDue.Text = "";
        totalItems.Text = "";
    }

    private void customerInformationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Customers.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name: " + Customers.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text + "\n" +
                            "Adress: " + Customers.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text + "\n" +
                            "Telephone: " + Customers.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text + "\n" +
                            "Order: " +Customers.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[5].Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: create a custom message box form using listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom message box by creating new winform that act as your messagebox.
Create public property on it to pass the value of your selecteditems something like:

Then on your form :

```
 private void customerInformationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Customers.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            var myformmessagedialog = new MyFormMessageDialog
            {

name = Customers.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text,
adress=Customers.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text,
telephone=Customers.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text
              };
              myformmessagedialog.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Your MessageBoxDialogform:

```
MyFormMessageDialog : Form
{
  public MyFormMessageDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string name;
    public string adress;
    public string telephone;

     private void MyFormMessageDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lblName.Text = name;
        lbladdress.Text = adress;
        telephone.Text telephone;

       //if you are saving ado.net stuff 
       //query username where name = name then bind it on a list box or a combo box 
       var Orderdata = //you retrieve info via DataTable;
       lstOder.Items.Clear();
       foreach (DataRow data in Orderdata.Rows)
            {
                var lvi = new ListViewItem(data["Order"].ToString());
                // Add the list items to the ListView
                lstlstOder.Items.Add(lvi);
       }


    }
 }
```

Hope this help you.
Regards

Comment: Thank you. I went to sleep so and I just woke up with good news :)